# counting the number of digits in a integer before playing a guessing game

Tags: java

the application is a simple guessing game which i got that part down. my issue is making a method that before any guessing starts the player must first guess the right amount of digits in a number

e.g the guess being 314 and the answers has 3 digits in it then the guessing of too high two low starts otherwise it keeps looping until you guess the right amount of digits.

now i have created the method to do this my issue is a rather simple one i think but its a matter of initializing the variables and that's where i am having problems.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NumberGuess
{                  
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        final int MAX = 1000;
        int answer, guess; 


        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random generator = new Random(); //Random generator. 1 to 100.
        answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) +1;
        guess = Keyboard.nextInt();




        System.out.print ("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and "+ MAX + ". Guess what it is: (or enter 0 to quit) "); 

      do
        {
            System.out.print("Guess what the number is: ");
            guess = Keyboard.nextInt();

            if (guess > answer && guess != 0)
                System.out.println("Your guess is too high!");

            else if (guess < answer && guess !=0)
                System.out.println("Your guess is too low!");

               if(guess==0)
                System.out.println("you have ended your game");   

            else if (guess == answer)
                System.out.println("You got it!");

        } while (guess != answer&& guess!=0);

    }
    int NumOfDigits(int number)
          {
             int numDigits = 0;
             while (number/10 > 0);
             {
                number = number/10;
                numDigits++;
             } 
             return numDigits;
          }

    int  guess;
    Scanner Keyboard1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    guess = Keyboard1.nextInt();
    int target = NumOfDigits(answer);

          while(NumOfDigits(guess) != target);
            { 
               System.out.println("read anothrer input guess");
               guess = Keyboard1.nextInt(); 
            }
            System.out.println("you got the correct number of digits now guess the number!");
            guess = Keyboard1.nextInt(); 
}
```

Comment: then the guessing of too high two low starts otherwise it keeps looping until you guess the right amount of digits? ... not clear what does too high too low mean?

Comment: The code as given doesn't compile; and even if it did, NumOfDigits() is not called by the main() method. And NumOfDigits() has an off-by-one error (hint: the numbers 0 through 9 all have 1 digit).

Comment: but really the number of digits is the log10 of the number

Answer (score 0):

your method for counting diigits is wrong it should be like this

```
public static int NumOfDigits(int number)
{
          int numofdigits = 0;   

    while(number>0){
        numofdigits++;
        number = number/10;
    }

    return numofdigits;
 }
```

because your method returns 2 and it should return 3